# Remove gap between cell and navbar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I implemented [ENSwiftSideMenu](https://github.com/evnaz/ENSwiftSideMenu) in my app, (you can just use the sample project it provided, because it has the same problem,) and when I rotate the iPhone to portrait mode, the menu `tableView` has a gap between the nav bar and the cells

[image]

I found the problem. It's at the following file: [MyMenuTableViewController.swift](https://github.com/evnaz/ENSwiftSideMenu/blob/master/Example/SwiftSideMenu/MyMenuTableViewController.swift#L17)

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(64.0, 0, 0, 0)
```

So I replaced the height of 64 with the height of the `navbar`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height, 0, 0, 0) // Error
}

override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height, 0, 0, 0)
}
```

When I run the app, I get the following error at the code in `viewDidLoad`:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

That error before the first page loads (at the splash screen). What can I do to fix that? Or if there's a better way to remove the gap please let me know. I already tried adding the following in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true
```

And that doesn't do anything.

Comment: What happen if you remove the `contentInset` lines?

Comment: The menu/tableView goes all the way on top, hidden behind the `navbar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've been looking how ENSwiftSideMenu works. It looks like your side menu isn't added to the navigation stack, so if you call self.navigationController, it returns nil always.

Also, ENSwiftSideMenu uses a custom navigation controller: `ENSideMenuNavigationController` that have a property called `sideMenu`, which unfortunately, inherits from NSObject (not from UIViewController). So basically, what I had to do was to change `MyNavigationController` class so it holds a reference to the `MyMenuTableViewController` used as a side menu, and apply content insets to it's tableview based on the `ENSideMenuNavigationController`'s navigation bar size.

Lastly, you need to apply side table view's `contentInset` after the rotation was made, so you need to observe `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` notification.

This is how `MyNavigationController` class should be to work:

```
class MyNavigationController: ENSideMenuNavigationController, ENSideMenuDelegate {

    private let menuTableViewController = MyMenuTableViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sideMenu = ENSideMenu(sourceView: self.view, menuViewController: menuTableViewController, menuPosition:.Left)
        //sideMenu?.delegate = self //optional
        sideMenu?.menuWidth = 180.0 // optional, default is 160
        //sideMenu?.bouncingEnabled = false

        // make navigation bar showing over side menu
        view.bringSubviewToFront(navigationBar)

        menuTableViewController.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.navigationBar.frame.height + self.navigationBar.frame.origin.y, 0, 0, 0)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "rotated", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func rotated() {
        menuTableViewController.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.navigationBar.frame.height + self.navigationBar.frame.origin.y, 0, 0, 0)
    }

    // MARK: - ENSideMenu Delegate
    func sideMenuWillOpen() {
        println("sideMenuWillOpen")
    }

    func sideMenuWillClose() {
        println("sideMenuWillClose")
    }

    func sideMenuDidClose() {
        println("sideMenuDidClose")
    }

    func sideMenuDidOpen() {
        println("sideMenuDidOpen")
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I tried it, but it didn't have any effect on it. Did it work on the sample project?

Comment: Yes, it worked there. Please check that you doesn't have any changes in other sources. I just downloaded the example again and copy pasted my implementation of `MyNavigationController ` to check if it works, and it worked :)

Comment: Thanks you so much!!! It finally works!! What happened was in `viewDidLoad` at `sideMenu = ENSideMenu...` for `menuViewController` I set it to the `class`, not the `variable` of `menuTableViewController`. Thank you very much!! I've been trying to fix this for a while!!

Comment: Just 1 question: What's the point of adding `self.navigationBar.frame.origin.y` to the insets y position? Won't it always be 0?

Comment: In portrait, the navigation bar doesn't start at the top of the screen, instead it starts above the status bar. So basically what you're doing there is add the status bar height + navigation bar height